# how to apply princomp with more variables on eeg data

Tags: pca

i have a data set of eeg recordings with 5000 rows and 59 coloumns. as coloumns are channels of eeg headsets and rows represents signal amplitude at each channel. now i used princomp to reduce the dimensions. but i am confused in variable and observation as i have a lable vector of 5000 elements to classify tha data but if i used princomp at 5000x59 i got 59x59 matrix which can't be classified by given label and if i apply command on 59x5000 data i got 5000x5000 matrix it means pca increase the dimension instead of decreasing. so kindly make me understand how can i percept variables and observation in my data.
thnx

Answer (score 0):

The Matlab command `princomp` can have multiple return values. If we denote your original 5000x59 data matrix as `D`, then

`[C, S] = princomp(D)`;

gives you the principal component coefficients `C` (59x59), and the actual principal components `S` (5000x59), where `C` is the projection from the original space to the principal component space, and `S` contains the actual principal components as its columns. The relationship of the 3 matrices is

`D * C` = `S`

Btw, if you only care about the principal components `S` and don't need the coefficients `C`, you can do

`[~, S] = princomp(D)`;

For more details, check out the official Matlab `princomp` [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/princomp.html).